# Increase height and width of google sign in button

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a google sign in button and this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".login">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:buttonSize="wide"
        app:colorScheme="dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my java file

```
package com.fireflyelectric.felcosfa;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class login extends  AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_DARK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result );
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            final GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String email = acct.getEmail();

            /* Compare email if exist in database */

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

}
```

my question is how can I enlarge it? Same with the google sign in button used in website

This is the 2 files on my app. I dont know where are the other parts that i need to configure. Maybe the code from the java inherits the xml

I hope someone could help me on this. I am new to android prog.

Comment: you mean the text of button ?

Comment: atleast the size on this page https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines the blue sign in

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following snippet. Set the `layout_width` of the button to `wrap_content` since the SignInButton sets the size through the `app:buttonSize` parameter.

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:buttonSize="wide"
        app:colorScheme="dark" />
```

You can set the `app:buttonSize` from the following : `wide`, `standard` and `icon_only`.

You could also set the size of the Button programmatically :

```
// Set the dimensions of the sign-in button.
SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
```

Comment: it remains the small atleast the size on this site developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines

Comment: Maybe there is another element interfering with it. Can you post the whole layout code?

Answer (score 1):

Make custom signin button look like that and add listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement, try following custom method :

```
private void updateGoogleBtnUi() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

SignInButton googleButton = (SignInButton) 
findViewById(R.id.google_button);
googleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});

for (int i = 0; i < googleButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = googleButton.getChildAt(i);

    if (v instanceof TextView)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        tv.setTextSize(14);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        tv.setText("My Text");
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        tv.setSingleLine(true);
        tv.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = tv.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = 100;
        params.height = 70;
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);

        return;
     }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.